# Translation and meaning of "He/She is a keeper"

Tags: expressions, traduction

J'ai souvent entendu cette expression dans des chansons, ou des séries télé mais je n'ai jamais complètement saisi son sens.

Que veut dire l'expression :

> "he/she is a keeper"

dans un contexte de relation "*amoureuse*" ?

Et comment la traduire ?

Comment: La question porte sur la signification d'une expression anglaise. Je suggère de la mettre plutôt dans le stackexchange sur la langue anglaise.

Comment: C'est plus pour la traduction que j'ai posté cette question. Mais si un modérateur veut la scinder en deux, libre à lui.

Comment: "Keeper" provient de l'expression familière "for keeps {pour toujours}". C’est un homme ou une femme à garder {*keep*} pour toujours, c'est-à-dire "the ideal husband/wife material". Alors, si on a la chance de l’avoir comme copin(e), attention à ne pas se voir larguer tout d'un coup !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cela signifie que cette personne est dotée de telles qualités attendues d'un partenaire amoureux qu'il faut la garder à tout prix. On peut l'utiliser aussi dans un contexte professionnel, pour dire qu'un collaborateur a démontré de telles compétences qu'il faut veiller à ne pas le laisser partir. On peut traduire, selon le contexte, par des expressions comme:

> C'est une perle rare
>
> Celle-là/celui-là, ne le/la laisse pas partir
>
> C'est le mari/l'épouse idéale
>
> C'est un homme/une femme à marier

Comment: All of these are good, but I like your first one (“une perle rare”) the most because of its connection with something taken (and being worthy of keeping) from the sea, just as the original use of “[That’s] [a keeper](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/keeper)” (#3) in English (at least as I’ve always interpreted it)  was for describing a fish that meets the [legal size] requirements for being “kept” by fishermen.

Answer (score 0):

D'après ce que j'ai pu lire, c'est une expression utilisée en parlant d'une personne qui démontre des comportements jugés positifs et qui mérite d'être "gardé" (keeper du coup) dans une relation amoureuse.
Je ne connais pas d'équivalent en français personnellement.